# Is a null model the same thing as a null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, model

Just started studying statistics and am getting confused.

Is a null model the same thing as a null hypothesis? If not, what is it?

Comment: This appears to have [already been answered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/259641/71679).

Comment: I think the linked question is more specific (being about regression)..